# Bootstrap Close Subdropdown on main dropdown closure

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm currently working on a bootstrap menu on an ASP.NET application. To do that, I did a navbar by myself, and when I click on the button, it shows the menu like that:

[image]

That I wanted and worked well (All the code will be later). Then I want to create some submenus which appear when I click for example on the second choice: "Fiche". So after some research, I find that I can do it with bootstrap navbar like this:

[image]

That's almost what I wanted! (Excepted that it's ugly and that I don't know how to make it look better, but that's another problem.)
But then what I want is that when I click somewhere else than on my menu, all the menu disappear and that when I click again to open it, it doesn't show again the submenus I previously open (Basically, I want to close all).

And this part... doesn't work, firstly because it close If I click somewhere but it doesn't close the submenus, and I have no idea about how I can do this properly, I already tried to use .attr and try to remove manually bootstrap attributes, but it seems to don't be a good way of doing it. So I will post the actual code, which approximately work except for submenu closure (Also, I'm quite new to this community, I'm still testing how to do a proper post, so hope I have put enough information) On the snippet it doesn't seem to work, probably because of the lake of bootstrap which can lead to the differences in my configuration:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.immune-nav-close')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.well
{
    background-color: #219cdc !important;
}

.top-navbar
{
 background-color: #00448a;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
    
.menu-btn
{
 margin-left: 2%;
 height: 75%;
 width: 40px;
 max-width: 40px;
 display: inline-block;
}
   
.span-menu
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 margin-bottom:10%;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
   
.dropdown-content 
{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #219cdc;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 top: 60px;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}
   
.dropdown-content a 
{
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}
   
.dropdown-content a:hover {color: black; background-color:white;}
   
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="top-navbar">
   <a class="menu-btn immune-nav-close" href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">
    <div class="span-menu immune-nav-close"></div>
    <div class="span-menu immune-nav-close"></div>
    <div class="span-menu immune-nav-close"></div>
   </a>
   <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="/Default.aspx">Accueil</a>
    <a class="immune-nav-close" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFiche" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFiche">
                    Fiches
                </a>
                <div class="collapse ddown-nav" id="collapseFiche">
                    <div class="well">
                      <a href="/SaisieFiche.aspx">Saisir une fiche</a>
                      <a href="/MyFiches.aspx">Mes fiches</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <a href="/Approbation.aspx">Approbations</a>
                <a href="/Validation.aspx">Validation RH</a>
                <a class="immune-nav-close" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExport" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExport">
                    Exportations
                </a>
                <div class="collapse ddown-nav" id="collapseExport">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a href="/Synthese.aspx">Synthèse</a>
                        <a href="/Monthly.aspx">Bilan Mensuel</a>
                        <a href="/Personnal.aspx">Bilan Personnel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="immune-nav-close" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSetting" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSetting">
                    Configuration
                </a>
                <div class="collapse ddown-nav" id="collapseSetting">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a href="/Config_pays.aspx">Paramétrage Pays</a>
                        <a href="/Config_csp.aspx">Paramétrage Catégories Socio-Professionnelles</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
   </div>
        </nav>
```

Fell free to ask if more information is needed! Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the answer was quite "simple" but needed some things before.

Firstly I have some JS version problem that I corrected in hope it was that (because I couldn't use .collapse on the element I wanted) But then I understood that it must be applied on the `<div>` with the content of the collapse and so it work much better !

So I just had to replace my javascript by that:

```
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.immune-nav-close')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }

        $('.ddown-nav').collapse('hide')
    }
}
```